# How to configure environment variables for ionic v1 build?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, environment

I am working on a project that uses Ionic v1. Right now when I am developing on my local computer, I connect to my local web-service but when the application is built with

```
cordova build android --release
```

in order to build to Android app. The step I need to do is to always replace the URL from my local web-service to the production web-service.

When the Angular 7 released, I had a chance to try it, and as a result, I love it so much especially the [environment variables](https://www.joshmorony.com/production-development-environment-variables-in-ionic-angular/) part where you can configure the variables according to the environment you are using or serving to.

Here comes the question.

Is there an environment variables system like what I just mentioned in Ionic v1? If it has then please guide me the way. If not then please help me get a workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got myself an answer to solve this question.
For anyone who is facing this issue, you need to see [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/different-environments-for-my-application/15705).